# Java SerialPort writing rises up cpu usage to 100%

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I've a Swing GUI application running on WinXP on ~150 computers (same configuration each).

But on some of them (like 5), when the application tries to communicate with serial ports via RXTX (pos printers), java cpu usage rises up to nearly 100% and so blocks the entire machine.

The writing on this serial port is done in specifics threads. One of them looks like this :

```
... queries on the hsql database
... writing results in a byte array called "stream"

CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM2");
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Sending", 2000);
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();
out.write(stream);
out.close();
serialPort.close();
```

I first thought there was a problem with queries before writing but my application does a lot of queries in other threads and there're no such problems.

On these computers, the print time is variable (up to 10min during which the machine is blocked). On the other computers, printing is done in 2sec without rising up the cpu usage.

Have you any ideas from where this problem can come?

Comment: Try to print directly to the printer from command line to exclude system problem.

Comment: Do you catch PortInUseException? I could imagine from above code, that `out.write` blocks, because the printer is not "paying attention"?

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't paste all my code but i catch PortInUse, UnsupportedComOperation and NoSuchPort which are not thrown.

Comment: I'd measure how long the `out.write` is taking. Usual "suspect".

Answer (score 0):

suggestions
check baud rate allowed for both server and workstation
check the quantity of hardware RAM the sending machine has
check how much RAM Java is allowed in the jre config panel
check with anti-virus

Answer (score 0):

Try profiling your application in [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), which is included with the Java distribution (1.6 and later), while the high CPU usage is occurring. (You can connect to a running JVM to profile it.)

This will tell you which function or library call is using your CPU, so you can optimize or fix your code (if it's your code that's causing it) or identify the misbehaving library.

On Debian/Ubuntu, you can get VisualVM from the `visualvm` package. Note that the command to run it is `jvisualvm`, for whatever reason.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the soft i didn't know it. but as i said, my problem appears only on few computers, so i believe if it was my code, the problem would be on every computer.

Comment: @caRameL: It could also help identify that the bug is in hardware or a buggy library.